CDI decorators support in Spring Boot
I am trying to use CDI decorators in Spring Boot application.
Here is the CDI Decorators for Spring beans article, that describes the purpose and the way how it could be done. The article is pretty old, it is 2011.
I can add a dependency on new, CDI api into my Spring Boot project:
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.enterprise/jakarta.enterprise.cdi-api -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>jakarta.enterprise</groupId>
  <artifactId>jakarta.enterprise.cdi-api</artifactId>
  <version>4.1.0</version>
</dependency>

How to enable its processing? Is it possible with Spring Boot?
I cannot find anything in the official Spring documentations. For instance there are pretty clear documentation on CDI api, but nothing similar for decorators.
Note: please do not offer Spring AOP/AspectJ, it is another more general alternative for cross-cutting concerns. Regarding to the difference:

Decorators are outwardly similar to interceptors. However, they actually perform tasks complementary to those performed by interceptors. Interceptors perform cross-cutting tasks associated with method invocation and with the lifecycles of beans, but cannot perform any business logic. Decorators, on the other hand, do perform business logic by intercepting business methods of beans. This means that instead of being reusable for different kinds of applications as are interceptors, their logic is specific to a particular application.


The original article refers to the additional module spring-decorator.
That module is still using javax APIs, while modern Spring Boot relies on jakarta APIs.
A conversion to jakarta APIs is required in spring-decorator project in order for it to be usable in newer projects. The conversion itself may be as trivial as text search and replace but you would need to fork the project.
